# VBA Set Cell value to text containing ' not working

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to get a macro to type out a heap of formulae for me. The formula goes something like this:

```
=COUNTIF('other_sheet'!A:A,"hello*")
```

The user can specify A and other_sheet, so I select the cell and then go

```
ActiveCell.Value = "=COUNTIF('" & othercell & "'!" & column & ":" & _
    column & """,hello*"")"
```

But it keeps giving me errors like:

> 1004: Object Defined Error

I have tried using `ActiveCell.Text`, `ActiveCell.Formula` etc. and they all don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be `ActiveCell.Formula` and `",` is the wrong way around next to `Hello`. It should be:

```
ActiveCell.Formula= "=COUNTIF('" & othercell & "'!" & column _
    & ":" & column & ",""hello*"")"
```

Comment: I think it should be like this `",""hello*"""`.

Comment: That's more like it :)

Comment: small sytax thing, but i generalised the problem. Thanks for the effort, though.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can only put proper, completed answers into a cell.

i.e. if the output turns out to be "=sum(A:A" and a bracket isn't closed, then the application throws an error just as if you typed it in manually.

Comment: It depends. If you format the cell as text first, you can put pretty much anything you like in it as it won't be evaluated even if it's a formula.